# Python - Pass a variable to lambda if it exists

Tags: python, lambda

I'm curious about how to make code more efficient in Python, I've got to execute an action, which may or may not have a payload attached depending on the length of a list.

Right now, I'm using an if statement to determine if there is a payload. Is there a better or cleaner way to find this?

```
                    #If payload, execute action with it
                    if(len(data) > 1):
                        action= mec.action(data[1])
                    #If no payload, then just execute action
                    else:
                        action= mec.action()
                    return action
```

Comment: What type of efficiency are you looking for?

Comment: ideally cleaner code / better logic. I don't think it's possible to make this more efficient in terms of time?

Comment: It looks fine as it is: if you remove the comments, the code is still understandable. The only things I'd change is the `if` statement: you don't need those parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is efficient as is - instead of optimising for efficiency, try optimising for clarity first.
If the code then becomes a performance hotspot... think about looking at the efficiency.

---

Remembering that a `return` ends a function; this is a slightly cleaner alternative:

```
# execute with payload if exists
if(len(data) > 1):
    return mec.action(data[1])
# execute without payload 
# this isn't reached if len(data) > 1
return mec.action()
```

Comment: "try optimising for clarity first." This is something that can take a long time to learn in software. *Clever code* is the bane of maintainers, including yourself 6 months from now. Write clean code, profile the performance, then optimize what needs to be optimized ... and comment the crap out of anything even vaguely "clever."

Answer (score 2):

Python comes with vararg syntax you can use for this directly.

```
return mec.action(*data[1:])
```

(I'm assuming here that `data[2]` onwards aren't meaningful, or you could use `mec.action(*data[1:2])`)

Answer (score 0):

In this case just use a ternary operator like this:

```
return mec.action(data[1]) if(len(data) > 1) else mec.action()
```

Hope it helps!